# BubbleSort not working

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

It doesn't prints me out the array the second time.

It works if I remove the call to bubbleSort( ... ).

Can't understand why...This type of behaviour is never happened, why would the executor jump the second call to printArray( ... )?

Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

// STRUCT
struct Array
{
    int * data;
    unsigned int size;
};

// PROTYPES
void printArray( Array & );
void bubbleSort( Array & );

// MAIN
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Array array;

    array.size = 10;
    array.data = new int [ array.size ];

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < array.size; ++i )
        array.data[ i ] = rand() % 10;

    printArray( array );
    bubbleSort( array );
    printArray( array );


    return 0;
}

void printArray( Array & array )
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < array.size; ++i )
        cout << array.data[ i ] << ' ';

    cout << endl;
}

void swap( int & m, int & n )
{
    int temp = m;
    m = n;
    n = temp;
}

void bubbleSort( Array & a )
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size - 1; ++i )
        for ( unsigned int j = a.size - 1; j >= i; --j )
            if ( a.data[ j-1 ] > a.data[ j ] )
                swap( a.data[ j-1 ], a.data[ j ] );

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be **careful** with unsigned data types. At some point "i" will be 0, and you will check "j>=0" which is always true. Thus creating an infinite loop.

Comment: thank you. changed the inner loop with this         for ( unsigned int j = a.size - 1; j > i; --j )
            if ( a.data[ j-1 ] > a.data[ j ] )
                swap( a.data[ j-1 ], a.data[ j ] ); and it's working now